# vue-router - how to abort route change in beforeRouteEnter

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm seeing some behaviour I don't understand in the beforeRouteEnter navigation guard with vue.js/vue-router. I understand from the docs that this guard "does NOT have access to `this` component instance", but that if you need to get access to the component instance you can do so by means of a callback. I've done this because I want to abort the route change if one of the props hasn't been defined (normally because of a user clicking a forward button). So this is what I have:

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  console.log("ProductDetail: routing from = "+from.path+" to "+to.path);

  next(vm => {
    if (!vm.product) {
      console.log("Product empty: routing back one page");
      vm.$router.go(-1);
    }
  });
},
```

The idea is that I test for the existence of the prop and if it's not valid, go back (or otherwise abort the route change). From the console log, I can see that what is happening, though, is that the component instance is in fact getting created, presumably as a result of the callback being called, and throwing a bunch of errors, before the `vm.$router.go(-1)` kicks in and takes the user back to the previous screen.

So what, if anything, can I do to actually prevent the route change from completing if one of the requisite conditions isn't present, if it's too late by the time I can test for it?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  // Your code
  next(vm => {
    if (!vm.product) {
      console.log("Product empty: routing back one page");
      next(from)
    }
  });
}
```

You can read more about this guard in https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: That's pretty much the same as what I have now (and results in the same errors). The component instance is clearly being created before the `if (!vm.product)` test completes, presumably as a result of `next(vm => ` having been called.

Comment: Does you try `vm.$props.product` (product in prop) or `vm.$data.product` (product in data)

Comment: That gives me: "TypeError: vm.$props is undefined"

Comment: I now believe that I cannot do what I want to do using beforeRouteEnter. This is from the docs: "The callback will be called when the navigation is confirmed". At that point it's too late. So I need to find some other way of aborting a route change if the data is invalid.

Comment: If I understand your issue correctly, you can try to replace `next(from)` with `router.push(from.path)`

Comment: I think you're missing the issue here. The problem is not with the `vm.$router.go(-1)` or `next(from)` line - it's that by the point this is called, the component instance has been created and the errors have occurred because requisite props are not present. I think it's a logical impasse, though - there's no way I can check on the object without it first being created, by which point it may be too late to re-route (or at least, not without errors being thrown first).

Comment: Actually, that's just given me an idea. I have wrapped the `next(vm => { ... });` block in a try/catch, and put `next(from)` in the catch block. So if there is an error, it should redirect anyway. I'll see how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: `next(false)`?

> next(false): abort the current navigation. If the browser URL was changed (either manually by the user or via back button), it will be reset to that of the from route.

[Reference](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)